# Maven - Restful web service - Jersey - compilation error - package javax.ws.rs does not exist

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

The correct solution for this issue is still not available in the internet threads.
I have a maven project in eclipse for Jersey RESTFul Web Services. So, jersey required below libraries (21 nos.) are copied into project --> WEB-INF --> lib folder and project build path.

```
aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar
 asm-debug-all-5.0.4.jar
 hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar 
 hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar
 hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar 
 javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
 javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
 javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar
 javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar 
 javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
 jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar jersey-client.jar
 jersey-common.jar
 jersey-container-servlet.jar 
 jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
 jersey-guava-2.23.1.jar 
 jersey-media-jaxb.jar jersey-server.jar
 org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar 
 osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
 persistence-api-1.0.jar 
 validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

When i export this project as WAR file and deployed in Tomcat, the service is accessible. But the actual requirement is to run this service in WebLogic server where the same WAR file is not working. So, I has to create the WAR file using maven not by just export as WAR file.

Below are the steps i did.

In Eclipse -->Project --> Right click --> run as Maven build --> clean install --> run

it's still throwing the below compilation error.

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/karthik/Documents/workspace/Apple_DownloadFileWS/src/com/apple/downloadws/DownloadService.java:[6,19] package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/karthik/Documents/workspace/Apple_DownloadFileWS/src/com/apple/downloadws/DownloadService.java:[7,19] package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/karthik/Documents/workspace/Apple_DownloadFileWS/src/com/apple/downloadws/DownloadService.java:[8,19] package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/karthik/Documents/workspace/Apple_DownloadFileWS/src/com/apple/downloadws/DownloadService.java:[9,24] package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/karthik/Documents/workspace/Apple_DownloadFileWS/src/com/apple/downloadws/DownloadService.java:[10,24] package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/karthik/Documents/workspace/Apple_DownloadFileWS/src/com/apple/downloadws/DownloadService.java:[11,33] package javax.ws.rs.core.Response does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/karthik/Documents/workspace/Apple_DownloadFileWS/src/com/apple/downloadws/DownloadService.java:[23,2] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Path
[ERROR] /Users/karthik/Documents/workspace/Apple_DownloadFileWS/src/com/apple/downloadws/DownloadService.java:[31,12] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Response

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Apple_DownloadFileWS</groupId>
    <artifactId>Apple_DownloadFileWS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Apple_DownloadFileWS</name>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.23.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.23</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>2.23</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
                <version>2.23.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-jaxb -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
                <version>2.23</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>2.23</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Apple_DownloadFileWS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.apple.downloadws</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Service class:

```
package com.apple.downloadws;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;  

// Plain old Java Object it does not extend as class or implements 
// an interface

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML. 

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/downloadservice")
public class DownloadService {

  // This method is called to send the output txt file to download...
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "/ngs/app/alect/test";  
    @GET   
    @Path("/txt")  
    @Produces("text/plain")    
    public Response getTextFile() {  
        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);  
        Logger.getLogger("!!!!!!!!!!!");
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!");
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);  
        response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"sample.txt\"");  
        return response.build();  

    }  

    // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

May i know what should go into maven pom.xml dependencies? i googled and add the above dependencies and still getting the same error. Am i missing any dependencies here?

Answer (score 1):

You've listed all your dependencies in the `dependencyManagement` section rather than the `dependencies` section of your pom.xml. `dependencyManagement` is for managing the version and scope of dependencies, and is particularly helpful for transient dependencies or ensuring consistency across multi-module projects, but it doesn't actually put the dependencies on the classpath. To get the dependencies onto the classpath you need to list them in the `dependencies` section. The way your pom.xml is at the moment, your build has no dependencies at all.

Comment: Hi, i changed to RESTEasy instead of JERSEY and made the dependencies outside dependencyManagement and now it's throwing red color error in the project if i make the <packaging>war</packaging> type. Is there any error in my syntax? But if i Project --> right click --> run as --> Maven build --> clean install --> no errors and BUILD SUCCESS. is it correct? If so, how to generate it as a WAR file for WebLogic server using maven? The war file created now is not having weblogic.xml file. How to generate this weblogic.xml file in WAR using MAVEN tool?

Comment: <properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>JBoss repository</id>
  <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url></repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: <build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
   <webResources>
  <resource>
<filtering>true</filtering>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
<includes>
<include>WEB-INF/weblogic.xml</include></includes></resource></webResources>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>